# How to pass image url to another component as props?

Tags: react-native

This is my main 'App' Component code :-
I have made a mockbook set which i am passing to 'Bookitem' component for display purposes,i am passing the props author,title and coverURL(imageURL) for rendering purpose in "FlatList" .But my image is not loading but the author and title are properly functioning once i remove the "Image" tag.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Image} from 'react-native';
import Bookitem from "./Bookitem";

const mB = [
  {
    rank: 1,
    title: "Gathering Prey",
    author: "John Sanford",
    image : "https://du.ec2.nytimes.com.s3.amazonaws.com/prd/books/9780399168796.jpg"
  },
  {
    rank: 2,
    title: "Memory Man",
    author: "David Baldacci",
    image : "https://du.ec2.nytimes.com.s3.amazonaws.com/prd/books/9781455586387.jpg"
  }
];

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={data : this.addKeystoBooks(mB)};
  }

addKeystoBooks = books => {
  return books.map(book => {
     return Object.assign(book,{key: book.title});
  })
}



_renderitem = ({item}) => {
  return(
  <Bookitem 
    coverURL = {item.image}
    author = {item.author}
    title = {item.key} 
   /> 
  );
};


render() {

    return <FlatList
         data={this.state.data}
         renderItem={this._renderitem} />;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
     flex :1,
     padding : 22
  }
});
```

This is my Bookitem component :-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';

export default class book extends Component {


    render(){
        return(

        <View style = {styles.container}>
          <View style = {styles.info}>
            <Image style={styles.cover} source ={{uri : "https://du.ec2.nytimes.com.s3.amazonaws.com/prd/books/9780399168796.jpg"}} />
             <Text style = {styles.author}>{this.props.author}</Text>
             <Text style ={styles.title}>{this.props.title}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>

        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create(
    {
       container : {
           flexDirection: "row",
           backgroundColor:"#FFF85C",
           borderBottomColor:"#AAAAAA",
           borderBottomWidth: 2,
           padding: 5,
           height: 175
       },
       cover : {
           flex:1,
           resizeMode:"contain",
           height: 150,
           width: 150
       },
       info:{
           flexDirection: "column",
           alignItems: "flex-end",
           flex: 3,
           alignSelf:"center",
           padding: 20
       },
       author: {
           fontFamily: "Lobster-regular",
           fontSize: 20
       },
       title : {
           fontSize: 23,
           fontFamily: "Lobster-Regular" 
       }
    }
)
```

How can I pass imageURL as a prop ??

Comment: Are you not able to see `this.props.coverURL` in you ``<Book />` component?

Comment: Yes!! I tried it a number of ways , any help would be appreciated

Comment: One thing Im noticing is a certificate error with the domain that image is hosted on. That could be causing the image not to load.

Comment: Should i use locally saved images instead of using the image URL ?

Comment: I would try that first. Verify you can pass `coverURL` as a prop using a static local image, then fix the cert issue for the remote image url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there were a few problems with your code:

- You forgot to import `Image` in your Bookitem file.
- Seems like your URLs have an invalid SSL certificate, so you're not
  able to request them through HTTPS. Changing the protocol to HTTP
  makes it so they can be downloaded and shown.

Below's your code with the needed corrections:

**App.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Image } from 'react-native';
import Bookitem from "./Bookitem";

const mB = [
  {
    rank: 1,
    title: "Gathering Prey",
    author: "John Sanford",
    image: "http://du.ec2.nytimes.com.s3.amazonaws.com/prd/books/9780399168796.jpg"
  },
  {
    rank: 2,
    title: "Memory Man",
    author: "David Baldacci",
    image: "http://du.ec2.nytimes.com.s3.amazonaws.com/prd/books/9781455586387.jpg"
  }
];

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: this.addKeystoBooks(mB) };
  }

  addKeystoBooks = books => {
    return books.map(book => {
      return Object.assign(book, { key: book.title });
    })
  }



  _renderitem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <Bookitem
        coverURL={item.image}
        author={item.author}
        title={item.key}
      />
    );
  };


  render() {

    return <FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      renderItem={this._renderitem} />;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 22
  }
});
```

**Bookitem.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';

export default class book extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View style = {styles.container}>
          <View style = {styles.info}>
            <Image style={styles.cover} source={{ uri: this.props.coverURL }} />
             <Text style = {styles.author}>{this.props.author}</Text>
             <Text style ={styles.title}>{this.props.title}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create(
  {
    container: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      backgroundColor: '#FFF85C',
      borderBottomColor: '#AAAAAA',
      borderBottomWidth: 2,
      padding: 5,
      height: 175,
    },
    cover: {
    //   flex: 1,
      resizeMode: 'contain',
      height: 150,
      width: 150,
    },
    info: {
      flexDirection: 'column',
      alignItems: 'flex-end',
      flex: 3,
      alignSelf: 'center',
      padding: 20,
    },
    author: {
      fontSize: 20,
    },
    title: {
      fontSize: 23,
    },
  }
);
```

[Here's how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNfOk.png)

Comment: Thank You so much for your help !!
It solved my problem

Comment: I Can't use a local image! I stored the data as .json file and image prop = "./assets/image.jpg" but when I passed it as a prop to <Image> BUT when I use an image from the server like "http://books/9781455586387.jpg"  So how can i handle it to accept a local image @BrunoEduardo

Comment: @DevAS from RN's docs "If passing an object, the general shape is {uri: string, width: number, height: number, scale: number}". Try passing the source prop as source={{ uri: './assets/image.jpg' }}.